# update_attributes with none-standard form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have cobbled together a form due to some oddities in my code and routes. Things work for adding data to the database, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to update data. Here is some code.

**new.html.erb**

```
<% form_tag '/list' do %>
    Episodes Completed: 
    <%= text_field_tag "completed"  %>
    Watch Status
    <%= collection_select(nil, 'id', @show_status, :id, :state) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('show_id', @show.id) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<% form_tag("/list/#{@show_completion.show.id}", :method => :put ) do %>
    Episodes Completed: 
    <%= text_field_tag "completed", @show_completion.episodes_completed  %>
    Watch Status
    <%= collection_select(nil, 'id', @show_status, :id, :state) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('show_id', @show_completion.show.id) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Edit' %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller's Create and Update methods

```
def create
  @show_completetion = ShowCompletionStatus.new
  @show_completetion.user_id = current_user.id
  @show_completetion.episodes_completed = params[:completed]
  @show_completetion.status_state_id = params[:id]
  @show_completetion.show_id = params[:show_id]
  @show_completetion.save
end

def update
  @show_completion = ShowCompletionStatus.find(params[:id])

  @show_completion.episodes_completed = params[:completed]
  @show_completion.status_state_id = params[:id]
  @show_completion.show_id = params[:show_id]

  if @show_completion.update_attribute('episodes_completed', params[:completed])
    redirect_to "/list/#{current_user.username}"
  else
     redirect_to "/list/#{params[:id]}/edit"
  end
end
```

Here are my routes for these:

```
match "list/" => "list#create", :via => :post
match "list/new/:show_id" => "list#new", :constraints => { :show_id => /[0-9]+/ }
match "list/:id/edit" => "list#edit", :constraints => { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, :via => :get
match "list/:id" => "list#update", :constraints => { :id => /[0-9]+/ }, :via => :put
```

I have been trying different things to get this to work for the better part of 4 hours now. I think I am just missing something, but I just can't see it.

Is there a better way to do the form that makes it work better?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making a hash and passing it to the update attributes with the key value pairs of what the objects attributes would be. Since updates_attributes takes a hash and not an object it was a simple solution once the connection was made.

Comment: Since you are already assigning to the attributes directly, you don't need the `update_attributes` call, just call `save!`.

Comment: Like I left in the comment on the other one. Every time I did that it would insert a new record and not update the old record. I tried that several times to make sure that is what was happening. I kept changing a single field for about 10 times and i ended up having 10 new records in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `update_attribute` call for a `save` call.

Also, if you're writing everything from scratch instead of using the builtins, try to use `save!` instead of `save`: it will raise an exception if it fails, unlike the plain `save` that just returns `false`.

Comment: The problem I had doing that was it would create a new record every time instead of editing the old one.